# Java BankAccount issue with resource class and math

Tags: java, math, currency

I am working on a practice assignment to improve my understanding of driver and resource class, I have created a resource class in which holds my code for any possible Bank Account being created. I then need to output that account and it's information, here are the instructions:

> A. BankAccount.java and TestBankAccount.java
>   a. Assignment – text book (Project 5-5, p.197). Complete a UML summary for the resource
>   class. Write 2 constructors and all accessor and mutator methods for the field variables. Write
>   a toString() method.
>
> b. Output – should appear exactly as the output shown below. The balance statement will come
>   from the toString() method. Format the toString() method with String.format(). All other
>   outputs are string literals (in quotes).
>
> > Open account Mickey has a current balance of $0.00
> >
> > Deposit $500.00 Mickey has a current balance of $500.00
> >
> > Withdraw $125.25 Mickey has a current balance of $374.75
> >
> > Open account Minnie has a current balance of $1,000.00
> >
> > Withdraw $73.21 Minnie has a current balance of $926.79
> >
> > Open account Goofy has a current balance of $10,000.00
> >
> > Close account Goofy has a current balance of $0.00

My code for the resource class:

```
public class BankAccount
{   
private String ownerName;
private double balance;
public BankAccount()
{
  ownerName = "";
  balance = 0.00;

}
public BankAccount(String name, double bal)
{
  ownerName = name;
  balance = bal;
} 
public String toString()
{
  return ownerName + " has a current balance of " + String.format("%1$,.2f", balance);
}
public String getOwnerName()
{
  return ownerName;
}
public void setOwnerName(String name)
{
  ownerName = name;
}

public void deposit(double d)
{
  balance+=d;
}
public void withdrawl(double w)
{
  balance-=w;

}
}
```

My code for the Driver class:

```
public class BankAccountDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  BankAccount micky = new BankAccount("Micky", 0.00);
  System.out.println("Open Account      " + micky);
  System.out.println("Deposit $500.00      ");
}
}
```

I am stuck on doing the math for depositing, withdrawing and deleting the account. I believe I have the methods ready to perform such tasks but how do I output it?

Comment: "How do I output it?"  You don't have a method in `BankAccount` to return the balance.  Add a `getBalance()` method that does this.  Then something like `System.out.println(micky.getBalance())`.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that `toString` would display it.  But it's still best to have a separate method just to return the balance, because sometimes you may want to do something different with it or display it in a different way than your `toString` displays it.

Comment: @ajb: Look at requirement B of the question. He has done exactly what was asked of him in terms of the Driver class. But I agree that there might be better use-cases for the toString().

Comment: @JohnO'Mahoney Thanks, I missed that.  I wish instructors would quit teaching bad habits.

Comment: Floating point should never be used to represent money. You should store the balance as a BigDecimal or as a whole number of cents.

Comment: I don't fully understand, can you please explain more?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic has problems associated with it. It doesn't return precisely the correct answer sometimes. See http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html . This is fixed in the BigDecimal implementation and is widely used in Finance Applications. It's a little out of scope of your question as I presume you're not legitimately trying to start a bank?

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the information! Heavens no, I am just learning AP Computer Science in high school. Does sound like a fun future project though!

Comment: @illusionist The comments are right about `BigDecimal`, although I wouldn't worry about it just yet.  You have to start handling about a trillion dollars before you start getting errors with a `double`.  Although I'm sure that Mickey and Minnie's royalties are probably pretty close to that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do indeed have all you need. When you want to withdraw $10 from `micky`, you just need `micky.withdrawal(10.0)`, and the corresponding thing with deposits.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was very confused on how to call my method, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need you just need to call `toString()` on the instansiated object.

```
public class BankAccountDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       BankAccount micky = new BankAccount("Micky", 0.00);
       System.out.println("Open Account      " + micky.toString());
       micky.deposit(500.0);
       System.out.println("Deposit $500.00      " + micky.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A few things:

1. For your String.format, try `String.Format("${0}", balance);`
2. As mentioned, you need to just call your toString() method to have the "has a current balance.." part
3. You have the code to deposit and withdraw, but you don't call it. So you need to call it, like `micky.deposit(500);`. Then you can repeat your toString() call to print it out.
4. If your having a problem with the actual displaying, try `Console.WriteLine()` instead of `System.out.println()`

Comment: You are mixing up two languages.  I don't know what the heck `String.Format` is in Java, and `String.format` doesn't recognize `${0}` as anything special.

Comment: (1) and (4) are C#. This is a Java question. If you know C# but not Java, you might be better off concentrating on the C# questions.

Comment: I totally am, stuck in C#, sorry!